# Converting curl to vb net

Tags: vb.net, curl

I have this curl command:

```
curl -X GET 'https://nebula-eu.kampyle.com/kma/api/feedback?startDate=1483228800' \  
-H 'authorization: Basic SomeKeyHere'
```

can you explain how convert this code into vb.net and download json file?

Comment: `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization` + [AuthenticationHeaderValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.authenticationheadervalue)

Comment: If you use the same HttpClient for multiple requests, initialize a [HttpRequestMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage.-ctor) instead.